# Cefsharp didn't start on Client Machine?

Tags: visual-c++, chromium-embedded, visual-c++-2012, cefsharp

What to add with `.net 4.5.1, Visual C++ 2012 Redistribution` inorder to make cefsharp work on Client machine?.

I installed both  `.net 4.5.1, Visual C++ 2012 Redistribution package` and the dlls

```
libcef.dll
icudt.dll
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.WinForms.dll
```

are all present, the cefsharp form didn't open up. Its showing exception `"Could not load file or assembly cefsharp.dll".`

I have tried installing `Visual C++ 2008,2010,2012` versions too. But it still didn't show up.

Comment: I also did everything as mentioned on Question 3, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Are you using CefSharp 1 or 3?

Comment: @chillitom cefsharp version 1.25.7

Answer (score 0):

If you have this same problem you need to use the release dll's.

The C++ dll's that were compiled as `Debug` use the debug runtime which is not available on a client machine. That's why it fails on the client machines and runs fine in the development environment.

[image]

Set the solution configuration to `Release` and then re-compile the solution to get the release dll's.

Make sure you use all of the following release dependencies:

- CefSharp.dll
- CefSharp.Core.dll
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
- CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll