# C# Compiled Project with Cefsharp Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a project using Cefsharp Winform. In VS2015, I am creating a setup for it and installing it to another PC. When I try to open it, nothing happens.

My Program.cs file is like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    var settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x86\Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";
    Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Applicatioin.Run(new Main());
}
```

But when I comment those line below, after installing, exe is working.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   // var settings = new CefSettings();
   // settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = @"x86\Cefsharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";
   // Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Applicatioin.Run(new Main());
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: did you control system requirement?

Comment: @erdiyılmaz which means?

Comment: install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It's already installed.

Comment: install .Net 4.5.2 or grater

Comment: .Net 4.6.1 installed.

Comment: Did you install them on client machine or just developer machine

Comment: Client machine. Also tried on dev machine. Either of them didn't work.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780653/cefsharp-didnt-start-on-client-machine